# Metor iron router - external redirect

Tags: redirect, meteor, iron-router

At the moment I have the code below - the problem is that the template 'old browser does not render for ie8. Can I do an external redirect to an external page.

```
Router.map(function() {


  this.route('main', {
    path: '/',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    template: 'main',
      onBeforeAction: function () {
            // render the unsupported browser page if user isn't using Chrome
            if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.version < 10){
                this.redirect('oldbrowser');

            }

          this.next();
      },
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `this.redirect()` just use:

```
window.location = 'http://externalurl.com';
```

You're not using ir to route at that point since it has no knowledge of the *external* route.